# SQL Group detail

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables.

Table_1

```
ProblemNeedsMeet    ServicesMeet              Count 
Education           Student Financial Aid       2   
Education           Alternative Education       1   
Education           ESL                         1
```

Table_2

```
ProblemNeedsUnmeet  ServicesUnmeet            CountUnmeet   
Education           Higher Education Awareness  1   
Education           Higher Education Bridge     1
```

I like to join so the data like this

```
ProblemNeedsMeet    ServicesMeet              Count    ServicesUnmeet             CountUnmeet
Education           Student Financial Aid       2      Higher Education Awareness   1   
Education           Higher Education Bridge     1      Alternative Education        1
Education           ESL                         1
```

My query

```
select m.ProblemNeedsMeet
    ,m.ServicesMeet
    ,m.ServicesMeetCount
    ,u.ServicesUnmeet
    ,u.ServicesUnMeetCount
from table_1 m
join table_2 u on m.ProblemNeedsMeet = u.ProblemNeedsUnMeet
```

Comment: What code have you tried so far? What errors or knowledge gaps are preventing you from solving this yourself?

Comment: You will have a better experience here if you read through [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then write your question with details to create [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). See [How to post a SQL question on a public forum](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for tips.

Comment: I don't understand what links "Student Financial Aid" to "Higher Education Awareness" and "Alternative Education" to "Alternative Education". What is the rule you are applying here?

Comment: A row of data in a SQL query result or a table represents the values of attributes, represented by columns, that are related to that instance of an entity, represented as a table. It's not a spreadsheet, where you can arbitrarily "paste" unrelated data points into adjacent columns next to another data set, which is what you seem to want to do here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to put the rows "side-by-side".  For this you need a column . . . which you can generate using `row_number()`:

```
select m.ProblemNeedsMeet, m.ServicesMeet, m.ServicesMeetCount
       u.ServicesUnmeet, u.ServicesUnMeetCount
from (select m.*, row_number() over (order by ServicesMeetCount desc) as seqnum
      from table_1 m
     ) m full join
     (select u.*,  row_number() over (order by ServicesUnmetCount desc) as seqnum
      from table_2 u
     ) u
     on m.seqnum = u.seqnum;
```

This uses `full join`, so all rows will be included from both tables, regardless of which has more rows.

Comment: I think you'd want to join on seqnum and ProblemNeedsMeet = ProblemNeedsUnMeet and partition row_number by ProblemNeedsMeet and ProblemNeedsUnMeet.  Or something like that.

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near '.'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near 'm'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
Incorrect syntax near 'u

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much Gordon Linoff